# I am struggling to put if condition to check whether additionalDataProperties are having Duration key or not in react.js code

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

**This is my data:**

Record { "DataActions": List [], **"additionalDataProperties": Map { "Duration":  }**, "name": undefined, "context": "I used to each cheese for a living." }

```js
  users = this.props.Users.filter(u =>
                u.additionalProperties.toObject()[USER_ADDITIONAL_PROPERTY_KEYS.Duration].some(durationId => durationId === this.props.durationFilterId));
```

I want to check in the above data in a such manner that whether the **Duration** key is available or not in the additionalDataProperties.

**Note: Above code is in React.Js**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map.has` function. You can refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has)

```js
const array = [new Map([
      ['x', 1],
      ['y', 2]
    ])
  ,
  new Map([
      ['a', 4],
      ['x', 3]
    ]),
    new Map([
      ['b', 11],
      ['c', 22]
    ])
];

const valuesOfX = array.filter(item => item.has('x')).map(_map => ({x: _map.get('x')}));
console.log(valuesOfX);
```